# Making a Javascript that are adding a number to an another number then adding it again to their result and so on

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script that are adding 10 to 10, then 10 to 20, then 10 to 30, and so on.

I mean, to auto count, by 10 by 10.

Comment: please add what you have tried - and what does not work.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could just do `10*(n+1)`.

Comment: Where I should add this code? I'm very noob.

Comment: What do you want to do. _Be specific_.

Comment: I want to make a counter. To grow up with 299792458 at every second. That's the speed of light, and I want to make how long the observable universe grew.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `++` operator, witch increments the variable by 1. Just use this:

```
function init() {
    var n = 0;
    e = document.getElementById("output");
    setInterval(function() { e.innerHTML = n = n + 10; }, 1000);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take instead of an [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

```
++n
```

an [addition assignment `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

```
n += 100
```

with a fixed value for addition.

For getting a number which has some kind of easing, you could round the number.

```js
function getRound(v) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log10(v) - 3),
        f = Math.pow(10, i);
    return Math.round(v / f) * f;
}

function init() {
    var n = 0,                                 // declare both
        e = document.getElementById("output"); // variables

    setInterval(function() {
        n += 29979245.8;                       // increment by the wanted value
        e.innerHTML = getRound(n);             // assign value to element
    }, 100);
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: It's working, but, can I add an animation to this? I mean ease, or something?

Comment: what should be the the target of ease?

Comment: the number, I make it like this: ` setInterval(function() {
        n += 29979245.8;                              // increment by the wanted value
        e.innerHTML = n;                       // assign value to element
    }, 100);` and it's too fast, maybe a animation to make it more smooth

Comment: Sorry If I'm not explaining well but i have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/sv4yu01e/ the numbers are switching instantly, i want it more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Gathering from your comments, what you seem to **actually** want is something like this:

```
var universe = 0;

show_value();

setInterval(function() {
    universe += 299792.458;
    show_value();
}, 1);

function show_value() {
        display = universe.toFixed(5)
    document.getElementById("universe").innerHTML = display + " meters!";
}
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv4yu01e/10/) shows what it does. I hope I have understood the effect you were hoping for.

The reason your code wasn't working was because of a cardinal misunderstanding of [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp); the second arguement is the number of milliseconds to wait to run the first arguement, your function. You currently have it set to 1000 which is a second, but you want it to run more times a second to give a "eased" effect.

You seem to want to do this in increments of 10, but you'd have to run your function *29979245.8 times a second*, or around every 33.35 microseconds. So instead, in my example it runs every millisecond, adding 299792.458 every time instead of 10 to account for that. To make it so that the number doesn't "jump" I also used [`toFixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp).